# How do I use the Elasticsearch Query DSL to query an API using Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to query the public [Art Institute of Chicago API](http://api.artic.edu/docs/#introduction) to only show me results that match certain criteria. For example:

- `classification_title` = "painting"
- `colorfulness` <= 13
- `material_titles` includes "paper (fiber product)"

The API documentation states:

> Behind the scenes, our search is powered by Elasticsearch. You can use its Query DSL to interact with our API.

I can't figure out how to take an Elasticsearch DSL JSON-like object and pass it into the API URL, beyond a single criteria.

Here are some working single-criteria examples specific to this API:

```py
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=woodblock[classification_title]").json()
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=monet[artist_title]").json()
```

And here are some of my failed attempts to have return only items that pass 2+ criteria items:

```py
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=woodblock[classification_title]monet[artist_title]")
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=woodblock[classification_title],monet[artist_title]")
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=%2Bclassification_title%3A(woodblock)+%2Bartist_title%3A(monet)")
```

And lastly some of my failed attempts to return more complex criteria, like range:

```py
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q={range:lte:10}&query[colorfulness]").json()
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=<10&query[colorfulness]").json()
requests.get("https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?q=%2Bdate_display%3A%3C1900").json()
```

All of these failed attempts return data but not within my passed criteria. For example, `woodblock[classification_title]monet[artist_title]` should return no results.

How could I query all of these criteria, only returning results (if any) that match all these conditions? The JSON-like [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) does not seem compatible with a `requests.get`.

Comment: Which syntax are you using? Can you send a reference?
This is the one in the official elastic documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

Also, what do you mean by "failed attempts"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I was lacking knowledge on `GET` and `POST`. I can indeed use the JSON-like [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html). It just needs to be sent as part of a `requests.post` instead of a `requests.get`, like so:

```py
import requests

fields = "id,image_id,title,artist_id,classification_title,colorfulness,material_titles"
url = f"https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks/search?&fields={fields}"

criteria = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"classification_title": "painting"}},
                {"range": {"colorfulness": {"lte": 13}}},
                {"match": {"material_titles": "paper (fiber product)"}},
            ],
        }
    }
}


r = requests.post(url, json=criteria)
art = r.json()
print(art)
```

Notice within the `requests.post` that the desired criteria query is passed through as a `json` argument, separate from the `url`.